# "Bei einem zweiteiligen Verb steht der zweite Teil - ob Partikel, Partizip oder Infinitiv - am Ende": stimmt das?

Tags: verb

Im Nebensatz wohl nicht ganz am Ende, aber auch wenn "das Ende", oder vielleicht besser 'die rechte Satzklammer', aus mehreren Elementen besteht, scheint sich dieser Grundsatz zu bewähren:
Er soll(1) .... (gegen Kriegsende).... hin(5)gerichtet(4) worden(3) sein(2).   Schade, dass man das Kino ...(einfach) ...ab(3)gerissen(2) hat(1).

Sind also Verbpartikeln, Partizipien und Infinitive wenigstens syntaktisch gleichzustellen?

Answer (score 1):

(Korrektur: "Zweiteiliges Prädikat", wenn es sich um mehrere Verben handelt, nicht "zweiteiliges Verb") -- Sind alle Bestandteile eines zusammengesetzten Prädikats syntaktisch gleichzustellen? Inwiefern jeweils? Da kommen verschiedene Fragen zusammen.

- Sogenannte "Partizipien" in Hilfsverbkonstruktionen *sind* Formen von Infinitiven, sie sind in diesem Fall also Verben, folglich absolut gleichzustellen.
- Partikeln und infinite Verben können alle als Teil eines zusammengesetzten Prädikats vorkommen, Partikeln sind aber häufig mit einem Verb enger verbunden als Verben untereinander. Partikeln verbinden sich nie direkt mit Hilfsverben.
- Sie können alle auch ins Vorfeld gestellt werden, statt am Ende zu stehen. Für Partikeln ist das allerdings nur eingeschränkt möglich. ("*Losgehen sollen* hätte es schon viel früher -- *Los* ist es erst gegangen als..." Hier geht auch die Partikel allein im Vorfeld).